# Django, prefetch related raises key error

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, prefetch

I have a query which executes a reverse prefetch related.

But raises the following error:

```py
KeyError at /api/group/
(1,)
```

which is rather ambiguous.

My models:

```py
class Farm(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    """
    Farm Data
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                            unique=True,
                            )

    farm_id = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                               help_text=FarmHelpTexts.FARM_ID,
                               primary_key=True)

    lose_certificate_on = models.DateField(blank=False)

    time_zone = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                                 help_text="The Time Zone of the farm.")
   
    # Some more field
```

Herd Model:

```py
class Herd(models.Model):
    farm = models.ForeignKey(to=Farm,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             null=False,
                             related_name='herds')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

my view:

```py
class GroupView(ModelViewSet):
    filter_backends = GROUP_FILTERS

    def get_queryset(self):
        # TODO:
        #       When the auth schema is chosen is set up it's gonna be .filter(user = self.request.user)
        query_set = Farm.objects.filter(pk=1).prefetch_related('herds')
        return query_set

    serializer_class = FarmSerializer
```

Now, I don't if it's relevant but the Herd model is a related object as well (group) which in turn as another related object (cow).

the Group model also has a foreign key to itself.

all the models have a foreign key and all of them have related names.

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 114, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 46, in list
    return Response(serializer.data)
  File "/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 760, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 260, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 677, in to_representation
    return [
  File "/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 276, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1263, in _fetch_all
    self._prefetch_related_objects()
  File "/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 782, in _prefetch_related_objects
    prefetch_related_objects(self._result_cache, *self._prefetch_related_lookups)
  File "/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1651, in prefetch_related_objects
    obj_list, additional_lookups = prefetch_one_level(obj_list, prefetcher, lookup, level)
  File "/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1764, in prefetch_one_level
    prefetcher.get_prefetch_queryset(instances, lookup.get_current_queryset(level)))
  File "/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 636, in get_prefetch_queryset
    instance = instances_dict[rel_obj_attr(rel_obj)]

Exception Type: KeyError at /api/group/
Exception Value: (1,)
```

Comment: add the complete error traceback

Comment: @Vincent but the relation to herd is reversed, shouldn't I use prefetch?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: @Vincent using select_related raised this error Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'groups'. Choices are: user, pastureyearplan